# Image / Voice Recognition in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, speech-recognition, image-recognition, voice-recognition

I am developing an application with Image and Voice recognition.
Do you have any source or idea how to do this?

Thanks,
ZaldzBugz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For speech recognition use pocketsphinx.  Static libs were created for it at
http://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit
to work on the iphone.

Answer (score 2):

XCode comes with examples for speech recognition (in /Developer/Examples/Speech/Recognition), and the class you'd use is [NSSpeechRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechRecognizer_Class/index.html).

Comment: The question doesn't mention any platform, but it is tagged iPhone so zaldzbugz is probably looking for something similar on iPhone. NSSpeechRecognizer is for Mac.

Comment: So it is. I saw "objective-c", and thought "Mac".

Comment: Hi Jonathan,

Sorry i forgot to mention that i was developing an iPhone application.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), well written in C/C++, can be used in IPhone for computer vision and image processing.